# How to unspecify the storage type of an index in MySQLWorkbench so that it defaults

Tags: mysql-workbench

On creation of an index in mysql workbench the storage type of the index is not specified (BTREE/RTREE) but is defaulted by the database when the index is created.

Having once selected the storage type of the index as BTREE (The only option in innoDB) I have been unable to find a way of removing the setting.

So in the 'Storage Type' field at the far right I have BTREE as below:
[image]

But I want to have it blank on the far right as below:
[image]

The widget shows BTREE and there is no way to restore the original state other than presumably deleting the index in workbench and recreating it.

Why do I care? It creates a break for me when comparing against the database. The less noise the better.

Does anybody know a way to deselect the value from the selection list once it has been set? I am running under OSX 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to unselect the once set storage type. Can you file a feature request at http://bugs.mysql.com so that this gets into our todo list? Thank you.